# Why is the `df.columns` an empty list while I can see the column names if I print out the dataframe? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

```
import pandas as pd
DATA = pd.read_csv(url)
DATA.head()
```

I have a large dataset that have dozens of columns. After loading it like above into Colab, I can see the name of each column. But running `DATA.columns` just return `Index([], dtype='object')`. What's happening in this?

Now I find it impossible to pick out a few columns without column names. One way is to specify `names = [...]` when I load it, but I'm reluctant to do that since there're too many columns. So I'm looking for a way to index a column by integers, like in **R** `df[:,[1,2,3]]` would simply give me the first three columns of a dataframe. Somehow Pandas seems to focus on column names and makes integer indexing very inconvenient, though.

So what I'm asking is (1) What did I do wrong? Can I obtain those column names as well when I load the dataframe? (2) If not, how can I pick out the `[0, 1, 10]`th column by a list of integers?

---

It seems that the problem is in the loading as `DATA.shape` returns `(10000,0)`. I rerun the loading code a few times, and all of a sudden, things go back normal. Maybe Colab was taking a nap or something?

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 10]]` this picks 0, 1, 10th columns. If there no names then `df.columns = range(df.shape[1])`.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Yeah tried that already. Says `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Oh now you mentioned it. I print `DATA.shape` and it returns (10000,0). I guess the problem is in loading, then.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa This is weird. I rerun the loading code a couple of times and all of a sudden things go back normal. Is Colab that whimsical or what

Comment: Strange.... Give the link to the URL so we can try it.

Comment: @gtomer This is the link: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HruH1PQRPPPwYvYvNZzjHpR1rZNFvUWN  I re-load the dataset a few more times and everything just works again....I'm using Colab

Comment: So your problem  is solved or you still need help?

Comment: @gtomer  Thanks! The problem went away all by itself ... at least for now. But if anybody has any ideas about why, I wanna know as well ^_^

Comment: Tried with your dataset. Works fine....

Comment: @gtomer Thank you very much! I have no ideas what happened. I changed nothing in the code. It just went back normal after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perfectly do that using `df.loc[:,[1,2,3]]` but i would suggest you to use the names because if the columns ever change the order or you insert new columns, the code can break it.

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to obtain the column names in the first place as well.